# I can't merge two xml documents using textreader and dataset objects

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, this is the error: `'column' argument cannot be null. Parameter name: column`

I want to append this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <Name><![CDATA[G5]]></Name>
        <Type><![CDATA[44214]]></Type>
    </product>
    <product>
        <Name><![CDATA[G8]]></Name>
        <Type><![CDATA[44]]></Type>
    </product>
</products>
```

to this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <Name><![CDATA[G5]]></Name>
        <Brand><![CDATA[Sim]]></Brand>
        <Price><![CDATA[14]]></Price>
        <Price><![CDATA[8]]></Price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <Name><![CDATA[G8]]></Name>
        <Brand><![CDATA[Sim32]]></Brand>
        <Price><![CDATA[143]]></Price>
        <Price><![CDATA[84]]></Price>
    </product>
</products>
```

Where my final XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <Name><![CDATA[G5]]></Name>
        <Brand><![CDATA[Sim]]></Brand>
        <Price><![CDATA[14]]></Price>
        <Price><![CDATA[8]]></Price>
        <Type><![CDATA[44214]]></Type>
    </product>
    <product>
        <Name><![CDATA[G8]]></Name>
        <Brand><![CDATA[Sim32]]></Brand>
        <Price><![CDATA[143]]></Price>
        <Price><![CDATA[84]]></Price>
        <Type><![CDATA[44]]></Type>
    </product>
</products>
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    Dim objTextReaderOriginal As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("original.xml")
    Dim objTextReaderToAppend As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("to_append.xml")

    Dim dsOriginal As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim dsToAppend As DataSet = New DataSet()

    dsOriginal.ReadXml(objTextReaderOriginal)
    dsToAppend.ReadXml(objTextReaderToAppend)

    dsOriginal.Merge(dsToAppend)

    dsOriginal.WriteXml("complete.xml")
```

The error happens on this line: `dsOriginal.Merge(dsToAppend)`

Comment: FYI, you should not use `New XmlTextReader`. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create` instead.

Comment: Exactly what is the exception you receive?

Comment: Did you get a ConstraintException? Your second xml spawns 2 tables: `products` and `price`. And none of them have primary keys. Hence merging would raise all sorts of constraints issues.

Comment: argumentnullexception was unhandled.  I think I need to specify a primary key somehow. Do i have to tell both datasets that they should meet on element "NAME" ?